# Extract all 'whole' character elements before a certain point of the nchars in R?

Tags: r, char, extract

Had a question that I thought should be straightforward, might just be my lack of knowledge around the grep() family.

Given a set of characters:

```
list <- c("the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog")
```

We know that the `sum(nchar(list))` is 35.

Is there a way to extract all 'whole' character elements before a given place in the `list` object, say before 10, 15, or 20?

For example, if we did 10, it should extract "the" and "quick" but not "brown" (or any of the rest of `list`).

Apologies for poor title - open to edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a logical index with `cumsum` to subset the words

```
f1 <- function(vec, n) {
    vec[cumsum(nchar(vec)) < n]
  }

f1(list, 10)
#[1] "the"   "quick"

f1(list, 15)
#[1] "the"   "quick" "brown"
```

Comment: Will accept as soon as time limit completed - amazingly fast response!

Comment: while I have your attention, could I ask how long you've been going at R?

Comment: @ReputableMisnomer Probably from 2006 (as a newbie).  But, don't think too much about the initial time one started because I first started in C++ before that

Comment: Always interesting to get perspective on the R/coding journey - I've only started in winter of 2016 - excited for the rest of the trip and hope to reach your level! Cheers again for the answer! (apologies for the extended discussion in comments)

Comment: @ReputableMisnomer  sure, you would definitely be able to reach any level . Practice, patience, reading, etc. are the key.  I have seen many persons in SO started within a couple of years and became excellent coders that I find it difficult to compete :=)